# PySpark NaiveBayesModel.predict error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to evaluate Naive Bayes model to classification. I can create and train my model , but i have problem with evaluate process. I use PySpark mllib library.

This how it look my csv file:

```
ID,SCALE,PRICE,SUBCATEGORY
30,3,23,1
20,1,45,1
:
:
```

First I convert csv file to proper format then I create and train my model:

```py
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("NaiveBayesExample") \
    .getOrCreate()

dat = spark.read \
    .format('csv') \
    .option('header', 'true') \
    .option('inferSchema', 'true') \
    .load("Project_List_Data_Set.csv")
# Split the data into train and test

c = dat.rdd
print(c.take(3))
data = c.map(lambda line: LabeledPoint(line[0], [line[1:]]))  # arbitrary mapping, it's just an example

splits = data.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], 1234)
train = splits[0]
test = splits[1]


# Split data approximately into training (60%) and test (40%)
training, test = data.randomSplit([0.6, 0.4])

# Train a naive Bayes model.
model = NaiveBayes.train(training, 1.0)
```

then I make predictions and instantiate metric object:

```py
    # Make prediction 
predictionAndLabel = test.map(lambda p: (model.predict(p.features), p.label))

# Instantiate metrics object
metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabel)
precision = metrics.weightedTruePositiveRate()
```

When I try execute last line of my code I have errors

```py
    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\spark\spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 171, in main
  File "C:\opt\spark\spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 166, in process
  File "C:\opt\spark\spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "C:/Users/Tomek/Downloads/docplex-examples-master/examples/cp/visu/job_shop_flexible.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    predictionAndLabel = test.map(lambda p: (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
  File "C:\opt\spark\spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\mllib\classification.py", line 620, in predict
    return self.labels[numpy.argmax(self.pi + x.dot(self.theta.transpose()))]
  File "C:\opt\spark\spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\mllib\linalg\__init__.py", line 366, in dot
    assert len(self) == other.shape[0], "dimension mismatch"
AssertionError: dimension mismatch

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:325)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After that I want deploy this model on IBM Watson cloud.

Comment: Your code fails during prediction (dimensions of the test data don't match dimensions of the training data / model) not metrics computation, but to be honest I don't see how it is possible, with code you've shown.

Comment: It seems to be weird for me, i based on https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html and https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/mllib-naive-bayes.html